# Batch files - How to do mass change of all specific variables using for loop

Tags: batch-file

The following code takes in all command line parameters of a batch file. In my case I have about 30 command line parameters and they are all numbers of 1, 2, or 3. I take them in then want to reassign them to other characters. I want each var, if it is a 1, change it to /*, if it's a 2, change it to */, if it's a 3, change it to #.

The first part works great, it's the second part of reassigning that I can't get the syntax for.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set count=1
FOR %%i IN (%*) DO (
  set var!count!=%%i
  set var!count!=!var!count!:1=/*!  <--don't work
  set var!count!=!var!count!:2=*/!  <--don't work
  set var!count!=!var!count!:3=#!   <--don't work
  set /a count=!count!+1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the way of accessing the *array* members.

In your case, the best way seems to use a temp variable.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set count=1
FOR %%i IN (%*) DO (
  set "temp=%%i"
  set "temp=!temp:1=/*!"
  set "temp=!temp:2=*/!"
  set "temp=!temp:3=#!"
  set "var!count!=!temp!"
  set /a count+=1
)
```

Comment: +1; ooh, not how I would have done it, but I like that simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think jeb has the simplest solution, but there are other options.

1) You can transfer the current value of count into a FOR variable. This is how I tend to do it.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set count=1
FOR %%i IN (%*) DO (
  for %%N in (!count!) do (
    set "var%%N=%%i"
    set "var%%N=!var%%N:1=/*!"
    set "var%%N=!var%%N:2=*/!"
    set "var%%N=!var%%N:3=#!"
  )
  set /a count+=1
)
```

2) You can use CALL to delay expansion of the outer variable, but I don't like this option because the normal expansion is not as safe as delayed expansion.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set count=1
FOR %%i IN (%*) DO (
  set "var!count!=%%i"
  call set "var!count!=%%var!count!:1=/*%%"
  call set "var!count!=%%var!count!:2=*/%%"
  call set "var!count!=%%var!count!:3=#%%"
  set /a count+=1
)
```