# Trying to save in variables batch file untypical command line parameters

Tags: batch-file

Wondering how to take in batch file command line parameters such like the following and store them in variables -

```
file.bat /* */ # /* /* */ #
```

I tried this and I get filenames for the ones that have a slash in them. I tried the hash (#) alone and it worked fine, but not the ones with a slash. Can I escape them somehow?

Reply to answer below - This was the part not working -

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set count=1
FOR %%i in (%*) do (
set var!count!=%%i
set /a count=!count!+1
)
```

The below answer solves it.

Comment: I don't think there is any escape sequence that you can use on your command line parameters that will solve your problem. Please show the code within your batch script that is not working (edit your question). I can guess as to what you might have attempted, but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've figured out your problem by looking at a deleted post in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12739725/1012053). In your deleted response (that should have been a comment or an edit to your question) you stated:

> Thanks guys, it works great, although I just saw something I didn't
>   expect. Looks like I have nunbers 1,2 and 3 in parts of the command
>   line that I don't want changed. I need command line parameters 3 to 26
>   only changed in this way so I'll work on that.
>
> One other note is that I went to this method because I tried putting
>   /*, */ and # directly in the command line and the return variables I
>   was getting were some filenames from my computer. I guess the
>   backslash was being interpreted as filenames somehow.
>
> Is there a way to use /*, */ and # directly in the command line and
>   bring them in as variables properly? If not I will stay with my
>   numbering method.

Looking at your code in that question I see that you are attempting to iterate the arguments via a FOR loop. That works great as long as none of the arguments contain `*` or `?`. Unfortunately there is no way to escape those characters to get your desired result.

The only good solution I am aware of is to use a GOTO loop with SHIFT to iterate your arguments.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set n=0
:parseArgs
set /a n+=1
(set arg%n%=%1)
if defined arg%n% (
  shift /1
  goto :parseArgs
)

::display the parsed arguments
set arg
```